# How to get average precision, recall, f1, accuracy of cross-validation with sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am using k-fold cross validation for hyperparameter tuning on the whole training set with Weka and it shows the average precision, recall, f1 of cross validation. I want to get the same results with Sklearn in python.

```
    cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    grid = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv)
    grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
    # print the best parameters
    print("The best parameters are %s with a score of %0.5f"
      % (grid.best_params_, grid.best_score_))
    # print the average precision, recall, f1, accuracy of cross 
    # validation with the best parameters found
    ???
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `classification_report` function from `sklearn.metrics`.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

Comment: Hi Simon, the link only shows the classification report on the training and or test data, what I need is the averaged performance on development set using k fold cross validation.

Comment: Refit best_estimator_ on train, predict on test; and then call the classification report on the predictions.